# Где хранить изображения?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Где будет правильнее хранить изображения приложения, например, аватарку пользователя и т. д.?

Comment: @Andrach, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Используй `nostra13 imageloader`, там очень гибкая конфигурация, размер кэша (диск/память), качество и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

В `context.getFilesDir()`.